# Picasa API with oAuth 2.0

Tags: android, oauth-2.0, google-plus, picasa

I want to create an app which gets all my albums from google+ account. I need to use picasa api with oauth 2.0 to accomplish this. Can anyone please guide me in right direction? Or suggest me any tutorial?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best place to start is the documentation for the PicasaWeb GData API: https://developers.google.com/picasa-web/

Comment: Example Java code already exists for getting the list of albums: https://developers.google.com/picasa-web/docs/2.0/developers_guide_java#ListAlbums